# Can I trigger a top and bottom filter from a drop down menu in control based on users choice for a analysis dashboard in AWS quickshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, visualization, business-intelligence, amazon-quicksight

I have a series of visualizations through which I intend to show the top or bottom most set of values based on users choice from a drop down menu in control.

I tried creating individual filters but don't know how to trigger them based on user choice.